# The union of a class (collection of sets) is a set if and only if the class (collection of sets) is a set

Tags: set-theory

Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be a class. I want to show that $\bigcup \mathfrak{C} = \{x: \exists C \in \mathfrak{C}, x \in C\}$ is a set exactly when $\mathfrak{C}$ is a set.

If $\mathfrak{C}$ is a set, then using the [Axiom of Unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union), we have that $\bigcup \mathfrak{C}$ is a set.

But I am unsure about how to show the other direction. Any advice is appreciated.

**Edit:** Would it be valid to do the following? Or am I using some kind of circular logic here?

Let $\mathfrak{X} = \{ \mathfrak{C} : \bigcup \mathfrak{C} \text{ is a set} \}$. 
Then $\mathfrak{C} \in \mathfrak{X}$ whenever $\bigcup \mathfrak{C}$ is a set, i.e.  $\mathfrak{C}$ is a set whenever $\bigcup \mathfrak{C}$ is a set.

Comment: "C $\in$ X whenever UC is a set" - it follows just from the definition of X. Shouldn't it be "C $\in$ X whenever C is a set, i.e. C is a set whenever UC is a set" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ = $\bigcup C$ is a set, then $C\subseteq P(X)$, so $C$ is a set.